# How to subtract quantity from table and update it in c# forms

Tags: c#, mysql, forms, visual-studio

I'm a student on 3th year of IT and I've found so much help from this forum, I am stuck with my project creating program in C# so I need your help. I have 4 tables in my database but we will focus on 2 of them materijal(Material) table and Skart(Scrap) table:

materijal Table(original) which has:

```
idmaterijal(INT), 
naziv_materijala(VARCHAR), 
kolicina_materiala(FLOAT), 
mjerna_jedinica(VARCHAR), 
sifra_materijala(INT)
```

material Table(eng) :

```
idmaterial(INT) , 
name_material(VARCHAR) , 
quantity_material(FLOAT) , 
measuring_unit(VARCHAR) , 
code_material(INT)
```

skart Table (original) which has:

```
idskart(INT), 
materijal_idmaterijal(INT)
```

scrap Table(eng) :

```
idscrap(INT), 
material_idmaterial(INT).
```

They are connected with Non-Identifying Relation 1:1. Now I have a Combo Box in my C# Form presented down below. I need to take from table Materials (name_material, quantity_material, mesuring_unit, code_material) and subtract the quantity that I insert in the textBox on my Form. For example I have 108.15 kg of HR in my Material table and I want to put 45 kg to scrap table , how do I do it in C#...

Pictures:

https://prnt.sc/hdvGuXJWNI0Q - My Diagram in MySQL (It is on my language but I translated every cell name for you guys)

https://prnt.sc/lgIRVTCOe670 - Materials Panel

https://prnt.sc/t1IGxpgJ8GHl - Choosing material via combo box in scraps panel

https://prnt.sc/6InfCPpezZga - Example on how I want to subtract

Down here I had an Idea so you would take from the picture skart panel https://prnt.sc/6InfCPpezZga and insert name_material via comboBox1 (it lists all of the materials from material table ... here I chose HR name of the material) and quantity_material via textBox7 in my case 45 with save button aka button 13 I need to update my material table by taking the quantity_material - textBox7 value and place in my dataGridView3 (witch is showing idscrap and material_idmaterial) code_material, name_material, quantity_material(but quantity I insert in textBox7) and measuring_unit , I know that placing it and showing with dataGridView I have to do the Inner Join or left join but I cant quite understand it ...

```
private void button13_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    konekcija.Open();
    //OleDbCommand komanda = new OleDbCommand();
    MySqlCommand komanda = new MySqlCommand();
    komanda.Connection = konekcija;
    komanda.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    komanda.CommandText = "update materijal set naziv_materijala='" + comboBox1 + "' where kolicina_materijala='" + textBox7.Text + "'";
    komanda.ExecuteNonQuery();
    konekcija.Close();
    comboBox1.Text = "";
    textBox7.Text = "";
    MessageBox.Show("Uspjesno ste unijeli izabrani Škart");
}
```

Comment: *textBox7 dataGridView3 button13* - you're allowed to rename controls. Always rename your controls if they will appear in code (labels I can forgive, unless it's for status like `label11.Text = "Update succeeded!"`, but the rest..)

Comment: *`update materijal set naziv_materijala='" + comboBox1 + "'`* - writing SQL that is susceptible to SQL injection hacking is the biggest mistake you can ever make in programming database driven software. See https://bobby-tables.com

Comment: *`naziv_materijala='" + comboBox1 + "' where`* - the resulting SQL will look like `naziv_materijala='System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox' where` which doesn't work..

Comment: I know I didnt rename any of the controls I will do it later now I am focused on solvong problems in this form and its my first form I am trying to learn here

Comment: *I will do it later* - it's actually quite a pain in the ass to rename the controls later, because a lot of the code bears the old name still (`button13_click` for example) - and then when you rename those sometimes you get errors in the .Designer.cs file where click handlers point to non-existant methods. Best to name them as soon as dropped on a form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct approach for code like this would be something like:

```
private void UpdateNameFromQuantityButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //konekcija.Open();  //do not keep a connection hanging around; keep a connectionString instead

    var sql = "update materijal set naziv_materijala=@nm where kolicina_materijala=@km";

    using var konekcija = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
    using var komanda = new MySqlCommand(sql, konekcija);
    konekcija.Open();
    komanda.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nm", materialNameComboBox.Text);
    komanda.Parameters.AddWithValue("@km", quantityTextBox.Text);
    var rowsAffected = komanda.ExecuteNonQuery();  //handy to capture this to know if nothing was changed (0 rows affected)
    konekcija.Close();

    materialNameComboBox.Text = "";
    quantityTextBox.Text = "";
    MessageBox.Show("Uspjesno ste unijeli izabrani Škart");
}
```

- use `using` on your command and connection; make a new connection object when you need it. Reusing the same one can cause issues with some databases. The number of MySqlConnection objects in your code is unrelated to the number of actual TCP connections to the database server because TCP connections are pooled by a mechanism elsewhere. Your use of Open and Close actually just leases and returns a pooled connection
- always use `@parameters` in your SQLs to put data into the command. Always*
- close your connection as soon as possible after you're done with it

<sup>* Unless the "data" is something like a table name or column name in which case it cannot be parameterized; try and avoid such scenarios - it's usually possible</sup>

Comment: Okey but still i cant figure out how to update the material quantity by subtracting it with quantityTextBox ...

Comment: OK, now I understand what the aim of the code is; I read the SQL and thought it was updating the name based on the quantity...

Comment: ..it's actually reducing the quantity given the name. That would be an SQL like `update materijal set kolicina_materijala = kolicina_materijala - @km where naziv_materijala=@nm AND kolicina_materijala >= @km`, and you might want to change your `quantityTextBox` to be a NumericUpDown rather than a TextBox so the user cannot enter non-numeric text

Comment: i.e. "update the materials table setting "material quanityt = material quantity minus X" where the name is blah and the material quantity is at least X" - i presume you don't want to go negative on quantity.

Comment: This would be a good opportuntiy to check `rowsaffected` - if it;s 0 then either the name is wrong, or there isn't enough quantity to satisfy the request, so you can tell the user that

Comment: Omg dude I love you thank you after class I will try your method thanks a lot, I will update you on this topic 

Comment: Thank you soo much it worked I love you my friend u just save my project for collage may I add you on this forum for future questions if I ever get stuck

Comment: I have another question how would I display sifra_materijala, naziv_materijala, kolicina_materijala (quantity) and mjerna_jedinica on dataGridView3 witch is on this photo https://prnt.sc/6InfCPpezZga but the quantity is @km, basically that amount that I used to subtract from the material table

Comment: That is indeed an entirely different question and would benefit from being posted as a new question but in short it could look something like `var da = new MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM materijal", connectionString ); var dt = new DataTable(); da.Fill(dt); someDataGridView.DataSource = dt;`